# MySQL retrieve results based on matching percentage or limit

Tags: mysql, limit, percentage

I am working on a project where people can search on dimensions.

We have the following table structure:

Product table:
width
length
height

People can search this DB by giving for example the following dimensions:

300x200x250

What we want is that we sort this result based on the best match. We the exact dimensions are found in the DB you will have an 100% match. So we do not only want to find the results with 100% match but for example 310x200x250 or 300x220x260 is also fine, except the match percentage will be lower.

We want to allow all results with a match of 90% or more or a limit of say 50 results.

The basic query is of course simpel:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE length >= 300 AND height >= 200 AND height >= 100 AND(FORMULE TO CALCULATE THE MATCH WHERE HIGHER THEN 90% OR MAX OF 50 RESULTS.
```

Any on how can give me a push in the right direction how to solve the percentage part and the max limit part.

Kind regards,

Erwin

Comment: Define "a match of 90% or more".

Comment: Good question! Let me rethink that part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```sql
SELECT *,
       CEIL((300/ width * 0.333 +
       200/ length * 0.333 +
       250 / height * 0.333) * 100) pcnt
  FROM products
 WHERE width >= 300
   AND length >= 200
   AND height >= 250
HAVING pcnt > 90
ORDER BY pcnt DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Output:

```
| ID | WIDTH | LENGTH | HEIGHT | PCNT |
|----|-------|--------|--------|------|
|  1 |   300 |    200 |    250 |  100 |
|  2 |   310 |    200 |    250 |   99 |
|  3 |   300 |    220 |    260 |   96 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4f06/8)** demo

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple version:
I assume you are creating this query with passed variables? 
Lets call these $length, $width, $height.
Assuming your columns are defined as INTs or other numbers, you can compare without quotes.

You want to use <> or 'BETWEEN' compares

`"SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE (length>($length - 10) AND length<($length+10)
AND (height>($height- 10) AND length<($height+10)
AND (width>($width- 10) AND width<($height+10)";`

Where 10 is your range.
if $length=100
translates to "length>(100-10) " etc.

You can also use BETWEEN
`(length BETWEEN $length - 10 AND $length + 10)`
BETWEEN requires smaller value first, higher value second

You could also create percentages: 
`length BETWEEN $length-($length*.1) AND  $length+($length*.1)`

Then 
`ORDER BY (height=$height AND width=$width AND length=$length) DESC, height*width*length`

This puts the products with exact dimensions at the top of the list, then the rest, with  closer the product dimensions are to the desired, the better they will sort.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this to get this query to work:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
        SELECT whatever,
               whatever,
               MATCH_METRIC(length, 300, width, 200, height, 100) AS match
          FROM products 
         WHERE length >= 300
           AND width >= 200
           AND height >= 100
       ) AS a
 WHERE match >= 0.9
 ORDER BY match DESC
 LIMIT 50
```

This assumes you have a match metric formula in which a perfect match yields a value of 1.0 and partial or near matches yield smaller values.

Of course, you need to work out your `MATCH_METRIC()` formula; you didn't explain how that works.

Let's assume that if you're matching one dimension, you want to use a fractional measure of how far apart the two values are.

```
     1.0 - (ABS(A-B)/A)
```

If you put 300 and 300 into this formula, you'll get 1.0, a perfect match. If you put in 300 and 330, you'll get 0.9, meaning a 10% difference. Then, let's assume you want to use that formula on all three dimensions, and choose the dimension with the worst match -- the smallest match metric of the three dimensions. Then you'll get this for your MATCH_METRIC.

```
LEAST(1.0-(ABS(length-300)/length), 
      1.0-(ABS(width-200)/width), 
      1.0-(ABS(height-100)/height)
     )
```

for a `MATCH_METRIC()` function.  There are plenty of other ways to compute a metric. You'll have to figure out which one is best for your application.

Here's a definition of a stored procedure to compute that `MATCH_METRIC()`.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS MATCH_METRIC$$

CREATE FUNCTION MATCH_METRIC(
        len FLOAT, targetlen FLOAT,
        wid FLOAT, targetwid FLOAT,
        hgt FLOAT, targethgt FLOAT
     ) RETURNS FLOAT
    NO SQL DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'computes match between dimension and target dimension'
BEGIN
    RETURN LEAST(1.0-(ABS(len-targetlen)/len), 
      1.0-(ABS(wid-targetwid)/wid), 
      1.0-(ABS(hgt-targethgt)/hgt)
     );
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
SELECT * FROM products, 
(ABS(width-300)/300)-1  as percwidth,
(ABS(length-200)/200)-1 as perclength, 
(ABS(length-200)/200)-1 as percheigth
WHERE percwidth >=0.9 
AND
perclength >=0.9 
AND
percheigth >=0.9
ORDER BY percwidth,perclength,percheigth DESC
LIMIT 50
```

I suppose that when you cannot return 50 results with more than 90% you want the higher percentages. You should also decide which dimension is more important in your order by